# Como exibir uma imagem com file_get_contents

Tags: php

Quero exibir a imagem depois apagar do servidor, também não sei se esse é o caminho a seguir.

Tentei isso, sem sucesso:

```
 if (file_exists('carro.jpg'))
 {
    $imagem = file_get_contents('carro.jpg');
    //unlink('$imagem')
    echo "<img src='$imagem;'>";
 }
```

Comment: o que significa exibir a imagem? você só tem isso pronto? Ainda falta muita coisa a ser feita.

Answer (score 3):

### Com o protocolo data URI scheme

O [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) só retorna o conteúdo *binário* da imagem, se quiser exibir uma imagem e excluir na mesma chamada você pode usar o [*data URI scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), assim:

```php
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}


if (file_exists('carro.jpg'))
{
    $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents('carro.jpg'));

    $mime = mimeType('carro.jpg');

    unlink('carro.jpg');

    echo '<img src=" data:' , $mime , ';base64,' , $data , '">';
}
```

### Com PHP e HTML

Se por algum motivo não puder usar o [*data URI scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), **você terá** que criar mais de uma requisição, faça o seguinte crie um arquivo chamado foto.php com este conteúdo:

```php
<?php
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

$path = empty($_GET['path']) ? null : $_GET['path'];

if ($path && file_exists($path))
{
    $mime = mimeType($path);

    //Muda content-type para que o arquivo php seja reconhecido como imagem
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

    //Exibe
    echo file_get_contents($path);

    //Deleta
    unlink($path);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

E no teu outro arquivo chame assim:

```php
if (file_exists('carro.jpg'))
{
    echo '<img src="foto.php?path=carro.jpg">';
}
```

Comment: Sua solução é uma boa alternativa é quase isso que preciso, a dúvida agora é; usando base64_encode para exibir a imagem vou ter problema se a imagem for muito pesada exemplo 8mb 10mb e a compatibilidade todos navegadores vão funcionar?

Comment: @Rose resposta editada