# Renomear arquivo depois de 1 minuto

Tags: php

Como posso renomear o arquivo depois de 1 minuto? A ideia é renomear o arquivo quando a musica acabar.

Parte do meu código:

```
 echo'<embed src="arquivo.mp3" width="1" height="1" autostart="true"></embed>';
 $NomeReal = "arquivo.mp3";
 $RealNome = "arquivo.tmp";
 rename($NomeReal,$RealNome);
```

Comment: adiciona um `sleep(60);` antes do rename.

Comment: Usar um sleep e esperar a página carregar por um minuto impossível não há outra alternativa?

Comment: Só com PHP não sei se existe alguma forma... O que pode fazer é enviar outra requisição via javascript por exemplo só para renomear.

Comment: Qual finalidade de renomear?

Comment: Criaria uma Thread para não interromper a Main Thread de recarregar a página

Comment: @Papa Charlie motivo para renomear é para o arquivo não ficar mais disponível depois da execução

Comment: Pode criar um `temp` do original e comparar a data quando for carregado, assim não estará mais disponível.

Answer (score 2):

### Com Javascript + Ajax

Ao invés de usar embed use a tag `<audio>`, pois ela possui eventos Javascript que pode combinar com ajax para atingir o efeito desejado, então faça assim:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls src="arquivo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" width="1" height="1"></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">

function request(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send(null);
}

document.getElementById("audio").addEventListener("ended", function() {
    request("renomearaudio.php?audio=arquivo.mp3", function(resposta) {
          console.log(resposta);
    });
});

</script>
```

### Somente como PHP e HTML

Você também pode fazer semelhante a outra resposta que lhe citei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151523/3635

Carrega o arquivo através do PHP, o HTML deve ficar assim:

```html
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls src="ouvir.php?path=arquivo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" width="1" height="1"></audio>
```

> Aqui pode-se usar o embed se quiser (apesar de ser preferivel a tag `<audio>`), ficaria algo como:
>
> ```
> <embed src="ouvir.php?path=arquivo.mp3" width="1" height="1" autostart="true"></embed>
> ```

e o arquivo **ouvir.php** assim:

```php
<?php
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

$path = empty($_GET['path']) ? null : $_GET['path'];

if ($path && file_exists($path))
{
    $mime = mimeType($path);

    //Muda content-type para que o arquivo php seja reconhecido como imagem
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

    //Exibe
    echo file_get_contents($path);

    //Renomeia
    rename($path, 'novonome.mp3');
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```